# encryption of fiber communications

Tags: networking, security, encryption

We have to connect one site to another using leased fiber ( theoretically it's a dark one ) in order to replace a radio link. All servers are in one site.
Both location now have Gigabit networks.

Can you please tell me, beside VPN ( which would require some changing in configuration of our devices and application ) what else can be used in order to have a secure communication:

- prevet acces to data transmitted via fiber,
- prevent unauthorized access to our networks through this fiber.

I have searched over Internet and seems that there are some "encryptors" devices ( SafeNet for example ) but the price I have found are high.

Thank you

Comment: Use quantum entanglement.  Problem solved.

Comment: A VPN is definitely the correct way to do this.

Comment: `which would require some changing in configuration of our devices and application` - What solution do you believe that you will find that doesn't require changing some configuration?  What change specifically are you worried about?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're defining VPN too narrowly. IPSec was invented exactly for this sort of situation. Almost all business-grade routers, any modern OS, and a variety of other devices can do IPSec. Take your pick.

Comment: "Take your prick" :)

Comment: FML - I wonder if there's an anti-oops plug-in for FF so that doesn't happen.